# Calculated field -> lookup latest value from an other table (passing multiple criteria)

Tags: sql, function, view

Hi I am unsure about how to approach my problem and I am going to explain it the best I can.

I have:
Table A -> contains  [ITEM ID] + Other info about my item
Table B -> contains  [ITEM ID] [OPERATION] [SUBOPERATION] [VALUE] [FLAG IS LAST]

I want to create a View that will return:

A.[ITEM ID], [Name of OPERATION 1](contains corresponding B.[VALUE]), [Name of OPERATION 2](contains corresponding B.[VALUE])

My issue here is that i want to return only the B.[VALUE] which contains the flag "LAST" in B.[FLAG IS LAST]

Table B can have multiple rows for the same [ITEM ID] [OPERATION] [SUBOPERATION] as we can measure the same item multiple times. I only want to return the LAST [VALUE] so my view should have unique combinaison of [ITEM ID] [OPERATION] [SUBOPERATION].

Hopefully I am clear with my explanation.

I tried this with a function and it seems to work but is that the best option ?

Here is the function i created :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLastResult](@OPE nvarchar(100), @SUBOPE nvarchar(100), @ITEMID nvarchar(100))
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS 
BEGIN
RETURN(
SELECT [VALUE]
FROM [dbo].[TABLE_B]
WHERE [OPERATION] = @OPE AND [SUBOPERATION] = @SUBOPE AND [ITEM ID] = @ITEMID AND [FLAG IS LAST] = 'LAST')
END
```

And then in my View I am calling the function as follow :

```
SELECT
A.[ITEM ID],
dbo.GetLastResult('0040',  '0040', [ITEM ID]) AS Name_of_OPERATION_1,  
dbo.GetLastResult('0090',  '0090', [ITEM ID]) AS Name_of_OPERATION_2
FROM TABLE_A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B
ON A.[ITEM ID] = B.[ITEM ID]
```

Here '0040',  '0040',[ITEM ID] and '0090',  '0090',[ITEM ID] are the Operation and suboperation passed as parameter.

I am assuming that this method is not really efficient since for each row it will have t do that research on table B to get the last result, altough the amount of record should rarely go over 10k.

How would you have approched this issue ?
I dont have a choice the data must be represented the way i described : meaning one field for each [OPERATION] [SUBOPERATION].

Any help, comment is appreciated !

Comment: structure and sample data of the tables would help here, in the view you are not using the joined tableB. where are the '0040' and '0090' comming from? always the same? user input?

Comment: '0040' and '0090' are always refering to the Name_of_OPERATION_1 .
Regarding the view I just showed part of it but i am returning as well some informations from TABLE_B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand the question,

but with the information given this should have the same result:

```
SELECT a.[ITEM ID], operation1.VALUE AS Name_of_OPERATION_1, operation2.VALUE AS Name_of_OPERATION_2
FROM TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B operation1 on operation1.[OPERATION] = '0040' AND operation1.[SUBOPERATION] = '0040' AND operation1.[ITEM ID] = a.[ITEM ID] AND operation1.[FLAG IS LAST] = 'LAST'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B operation2 on operation2.[OPERATION] = '0090' AND operation2.[SUBOPERATION] = '0090' AND operation2.[ITEM ID] = a.[ITEM ID] AND operation2.[FLAG IS LAST] = 'LAST'
```

so:
lookup latest value from an other table (passing multiple criteria) --> join with multiple conditions in the ON

Comment: Lol i had no idea we could join on multiple conditions ! 
I'm such a newbie, will try that and report :) 
In term of performance, do you think this will be better ?

Comment: Jut tried your way with multiple condition on LEFT JOIN and it works. Thanks

Comment: You would be surprised on how many people don't know that one. but if it answers your question dont forget to mark it. Others can see the question has an accepted answer and brownie points for me ;)